# Address unique icon

Tags: addresses

I'm wondering what algorithm is used to generate the unique address icon that Mist, MEW, Parity and Etherscan use.

Here are some examples:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Wow. I googled "avatar" and "icon" but not "pictures". Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I cheated by remembering I'd seen a similar question in the past :-)

Answer (score 3):

There are many, one popular is [Identicon](http://identicon.net/), making use of [Identicon.js](https://github.com/stewartlord/identicon.js). If you need something more graphical, you could even use [Robohash](https://robohash.org/) ;)

They all base on the same principle: Take a hash of whatever, and generate a picture out of it.